# mod_rewrite with MVC

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know there are already a lot of questions about pretty URLs and rewrite rules but I can't seem to find something to help with my particular scenario. I am creating a small site and using procedural PHP for my controller:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) == 'about-us') {

    include("views/about-us.php");

}
```

My URL then looks like:

```
http://example.com/?page=about-us
```

I just want that to read:

```
http://example.com/about-us
```

but I am not sure how to do this. When not using this approach, this worked for such simple tasks but not in this instance.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a go and post back after I have had a chance to try it.

Comment: @JimL, I tried that and it gave me: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)\.html$ /?page=$1 [L]` but when I add that to my .htaccess file there is no difference.

Comment: You should have removed the html suffix. `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work like this:

```
RewriteRule ^about-us ?page=about-us [NC,L]
```